# Legal email address gets bounced back

Tags: outlook, office365, exchange-server

Platform:  Outlook O365 
OS:  Win 10
Exchange Server in the backend
Cached Mode: On

The email is in the following format (single quotes included) 
**'First Last (Home)' <client@domain.com>**

The bounce back message reads

> The format of the email address isn't correct. A correct address looks like this: someone@example.com. Please check the recipient's email address and try to resend the message.

> Remote Server returned '550 5.1.3 STOREDRV.Submit; invalid recipient address'

NOTE:  The code below does not throw an exception even though single quotes are used instead of the double quotes mentioned in [RFC 5322](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5322#section-3.2.4)

```
using System;

namespace mailVerify
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string email = "'first last (Home)' <yourname@domain.com>";

            try
            {
                var addr = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(email);

                Console.WriteLine(addr);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [RFC 5322](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5322#section-3.2.4) the name in front of the angle-address must be delimited by double quotes.   Apparently the use of single quotes there is not allowed by the standard.

The error message is incomplete since it ignores the name that can appear before the address.

Comment: I've been going over the RFCs (even as far back as 822 and noticed that as well.  
However, I noticed that Microsoft's api will accept the single quote.  Very odd.  I'll update this post to show the code that accepts the single quote.

Comment: I just realized.  The RFC specifies how to use the quoted string.   However, the obsolete format allows you to use unquoted strings (e.g. Joe Blow <some@guy.com>)  This meets the criteria of printable ASCII characters.  The single quote is a printable ASCII character as well.   I'm concluding that the email is using an OBSOLETE format.